# How to suppress the Java plugin prompt in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, java

I’d like to stop getting prompted to enable Java in Chrome:

[image: prompt]

To be clear, I am not asking how to disable the Java plugin; I would like not to be prompted about Java at all anymore. Where might I set this?

Comment: I assume [Block all](http://i.stack.imgur.com/rrapd.png) doesn't work?

Comment: Block all blocks all plugins, which is usually not an option.

Answer (score 0):

The following should disable Java:

Preferences **-->** Show advanced settings... **-->** Content Settings... **-->** Disable individual plug-ins... **-->** disable "Java(TM) - Version: xxx..."

Comment: Wrong. That banner comes out when you **don't** have Java installed, so it's not present in the plugin list.